# jQuery logging in IE: how to get object?

Tags: jquery, console, internet-explorer

Via Firefox+Firebug one can write out to the console a jQuery object and the console will, in great detail, show you what that particular object is referring to in the DOM.

```
console.log($(mySelector))
```

In IE8, using the IE8 Developer Tools, I also have access to a console log, which will write out as above. However, just like doing an alert($myObject) all I get returned is a gneric object:

```
LOG: [object Object]
```

Is there a way to get IE to show me more detail other than 'this is an object'?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

One way would be to use [Firebug Lite](https://getfirebug.com/firebuglite) for IE with the same call to console.log. You can either include it as a script resource in the target page or save it as a bookmarklet in IE and load it whenever it's needed.