# Firebug Lite in IE suppressing console.log statements?

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, firebug-lite

The Developer Tools in IE8/9 pretty much suck so I'm giving Firebug Lite a go. So far it's completely defeating the purpose. Any tips on how to include it? The Bookmarklet link on the Firebug site does not work in any browser I try...

I'm doing some CSS3 fallback stuff in JS and want more details than [object Object] in IE. I happened upon the suggestion in this thread:
[jQuery logging in IE: how to get object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2217282/jquery-logging-in-ie-how-to-get-object)

I'm including Firebug in my document's `<head>` right after a few meta statements:

```
<script src="https://getfirebug.com/firebug-lite.js"></script>
```

I don't get any output from my document.ready statement or anything else for that matter. When I take the script out, I get log statements like normal.

Has anyone gotten Firebug Lite to work? What the hell is the point of Firebug Lite if it suppresses log statements? I'm not wasting much time fiddling with this but I thought if someone got it to work it could be useful.

Comment: IMHO firebug lite is not meant to be used in IE. Soon enough you'll have even more conflicts with it.

Comment: It is pretty useful. The point is that Firebug-Lite has the `overrideConsole` parameter set by default to true, but it will redirect the console logs to it's own window not IE's.

Comment: Ahhh I see. I totally forgot about the Firebug console. DOY!

Comment: I don't know what DOY means, but probably it's the same with Homer's classic " DO'H !!! "

Answer (score 5, accepted):

IE has the F12 key mapped so it won't start firebug but you can force it to work like this:

```
 <script type="text/javascript" src="https://getfirebug.com/firebug-lite.js">
{
    overrideConsole: false,
    startInNewWindow: true,
    startOpened: true,
    enableTrace: true
}
 </script>
```

Everything you need is on this page: http://getfirebug.com/firebuglite