# console.log() is defined but doesn't log in IE - empty console

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, logging, ie-developer-tools, firebug-lite

Javascript on a page in Internet Explorer (8 and 9) **with Developer Tools open** reaches `console.log()`, **which is defined** - but *nothing appears in the actual log*.

Things tried:

- Double-checking with `alert()`s that `console` is defined and that `console.log` is a function.
- Checking with `alert()`s before and after that the code does reach the `console.log()` line,
- Checking code for any IE fallbacks like `if(ie){console={log:function(){}}}`, removing links to libraries and checking code snippets for mentions of `console`
- Checking IE's settings and enabling anything relating to debugging
- Checking that IE isn't broken by loading a 3rd party page with `console.log()`s (e.g. http://jsbin.com logs "init" and "runner")
- Swapping `console` for `window.console`

So the console is there and active, but no console messages show up in the actual console (on either the Script tab or the Console tab).

What else could stop `console.log()` from actually logging anything, even when Developer Tools is open and `console.log` is a defined function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The culprit in this case turned out to be, of all things, **firebug lite**.

My test dev pages often include this to (ironically) aid certain types of debugging in IE:

```
<!--[if IE]>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://getfirebug.com/firebug-lite.js"></script>
<![endif]-->
```

Since it appears in text editors as a comment, it's easy to accidentally overlook.

Alerting `alert(console.log);` before and after shows firebug lite **changes the console.log function** from the native code to this:

```
function(){return f.apply(c,arguments)}
```

...which for some reason (at the moment, here) then does nothing.

Without Firebug Lite getting involved, `alert(console.log);` in IE gives this:

```
function log() {
[native code]
}
```

...and does its usual trick of logging if f12 Dev Tools is open and crashing if it isn't.

Comment: After posting, I just spotted this in "related" - [**Firebug Lite in IE suppressing console.log statements?**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9830287/firebug-lite-in-ie-suppressing-console-log-statements?rq=1) where the answer includes some tips on how to make Firebug Lite play nice